# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(cols, rows)) in create,

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I get this runtime error using threads with my function defined as:

```
void doubleThresholding(InputArray imgin, OutputArray imgout, uchar T1,
                        uchar T2, InputArray mask)
```

It is a function that segment an image using double thresholding, where InputArray and OutputArray are OpenCV classes.

This is the part of code that create the thread object:

```
Mat nusegmB;   
thread t1(doubleThresholding,rgb[0],nusegmB,55,60,cytosegm);
t1.join();
```

I try using std::ref() on rgb[0], nusegmB and cytosegm but does not compile. I get this message error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(cv::Mat, std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat>, int, int, cv::Mat))(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, unsigned char, unsigned char, const cv::_InputArray&)>’
```

If I don't use threads, I have not any problem.

Comment: The title of the post seems to not be relation with the code and the question in it, no?